# Sort cells in a TableView

Tags: xcode, tableview, cells, short

I've a problem with a UITableView. I've put a cell in first position, and when I push it, an int who controls the number of cells in the tableview, increase in 1 unit, and reload the tableview. But, how I do to put the cell I add in to first position?

Explication image: http://cl.ly/image/3b1A1V081Q1l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do that in you table data source; e.g. if it is an array, you rearrange the order of the elements in the array so that when it is asked for `– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, it returns the correct element.